# Unable to edit text input on loading kivy module twice

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm working on a project and here's the flow of kivy python modules. Video ->  Login -> HomeScreen -> Video (repeat).
For the first time, things work flawlessly i.e.

1. Video plays and on tap Login screen appears
2. User enters credentials and successful login takes him to Homescreen
3. Once a user clicks on one of the buttons on Homescreen repeat step 1

After this, the password textbox on Login screen is ineditable and cannot proceed further. On console it gives me a message:

> [WARNING] [Lang        ] The file ../login.kv is loaded multiples
>   times, you might have unwanted behaviors.

I'm using a kv file to load the controls in Login screen. I followed one of the [blogs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/QS5Cw0cA0Kk) suggestion to assign `on_parent:self.focus = True` to the control but I've two of them. Assigning this property to both controls (Login and passwd) makes only one as editable after the third step.

Following is my login screen code. Let me know if I'm missing any fundamental stuff.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: <UTF-8> -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, SlideTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from pysqlcipher import dbapi2 as sqlcipher

import os, sys
import logging

try:
    Builder.load_file("login.kv")
except Exception as e:
    logging.error('login::failed to load kv file')

class Login(Screen):
    user_id = StringProperty()
    user_pass = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(Login, self).__init__()
        self.user_id = self.reset_user_id()
        self.user_pass = self.reset_user_pass()

    def reset_user_id(self):
        return ""

    def reset_user_pass(self):
        return ""

    def do_login(self, loginText, passwordText):

        do_validation = self.validate(loginText, passwordText)
        if do_validation:
            LoginApp.get_running_app().stop()
            try:
                Builder.unload_file("login.kv")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error('failed to unload kv file')

            from app.HomeScreen import HomeScreen
            HomeScreen.HSApp().run()    #run another kivy python module

    def validate(self, uname, passw):
    #database handling
    return True

    def resetForm(self):
        self.reset_user_id()
        self.reset_user_pass()

class LoginApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    LoginApp().run()
```

Following is login kv file

```
<Login>:
    BoxLayout
        id: login_layout
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,50,10,50]
        spacing: 25

        Label:
            text: 'Welcome'
            font_size: 28

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Login'
                font_size: 14
                halign: 'left'
                text_size: root.width-20, 20

            TextInput:
                id: login
                multiline:False
                font_size: 14
                height: 14
                hint_text: 'Enter your ID'
                on_parent:self.focus = True
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                text: 'Password'
                halign: 'left'
                font_size: 14
                text_size: root.width-20, 20

            TextInput:
                id: password
                multiline: False
                password: True
                font_size: 14
                height: 14
                hint_text: 'Enter your pass'
        Button:
            text: 'OK'
            font_size: 14

            on_press: root.do_login(login.text, password.text)

        Button:
            text: 'Reset'
            font_size: 14

            on_press: root.resetForm()

        Label:
            id: status
            multiline:False
            font_size: 14
```

Another question is I'm loading/unloading kv files multiple times for respective screens. Does it creates a problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add all your of your screen configurations in one `.kv` file and load it.

**Why?**

`Screens` in kivy apps aren't like `widows` in other apps where opening a new `window` is basically creating a new instance, in kivy there is only one `window` that gets loaded with all the `screens` and once you want to change to a particular `screen`, the `ScreenManager` just hides the current one and shows the one you requested.

I also noticed you are running a new app for each `screen`, instead you should add all your screens to the same python module in the same app.

```
if do_validation:
    LoginApp.get_running_app().stop()
    try:
        Builder.unload_file("login.kv")
    except Exception as e:
    logging.error('failed to unload kv file')

    from app.HomeScreen import HomeScreen
    HomeScreen.HSApp().run()    #run another kivy python module
```

This code has to be changed, if you are not using a `ScreenManager` have a look at [this documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html).

**EDIT:**

Here is a small example of how `Screen` and `ScreenManager` work:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

app_string = Builder.load_string("""
SM:
    LoginScreen:
    HomeScreen:

<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Next screen'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'home'

<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Back to login'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'login'
""")

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return app_string

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

If you run this app you will notice the behavior of screen changes when clicking the button.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, is it possible to add that video screen as of the screens in the ScreenManager i.e. add it as a widget? Because the documentation says we can only add screens.

Comment: You can add a `screen` then add your video `widget` in that screen.

Comment: @w1n5rx I just added an example, try it and you will see how screens work